# If possible to run a Docker Compose comand before a job exe in GitLab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am new to GitLabCI, it seems GitLab CI is docker everywhere.

I was trying to run a Mariadb before run tests. In Github actions, it is very easy, just `docker-compose up -d` command before my `mvn`.

When came to GitLab CI.

I was trying to use the following job to archive the purpose.

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  image: maven:3.6.3-openjdk-16
  services:
    - name: docker
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
      - .m2/repository
  script: |
    docker-compose up -d 
    sleep 10
    mvn clean verify sonar:sonar
```

But this does not work, `docker-compose is not found`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of docker-dind [docker-dind](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-docker-executor-with-the-docker-image-docker-in-docker) and run the docker commands inside another docker container.

But there is limitation to run docker-compose by default. It is recommended to build a custom image on top of DIND and push it to gitlab image registry. So that can be used across your jobs